# How to move VSTS Release Stage to a different "parent"

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am building a VSTS Release Definition, I have a single artifact which is followed by multiple stages - they are all on the same vertical axis and have a line drawn from the artifact to each one of them.

**Is it possible to move a stage** so that it is placed to the right of a different one?

For example if I wanted to have them all lined up and happen one after the other and only if the previous succeeds.

The only way I found is to make a Template from the stage I want to move, add it as the next step of a different stage and remove it, which seems tedious.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Click on the bubble to the left of the stage and change its Pre-Deployment condition trigger from "After release" to "After Stage", and then choose the stage(s) you want it to occur after.

Comment: This works on Azure DevOps the same way (being an evolution of VSTS) but adding some extra terms for the search engines here